# Conditioning by both day and certain hour, not just day, in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, time

Say I tried running a similar script

```
let currentTime = new Date();
let currentDay = currentTime.getDay();
let currentHour = currentTime.getHours(); // 0-23.

if ( currentDay === 0 || currentDay === 1 || currentDay === 2 || currentDay === 3 || currentDay === 4 || currentDay === 5 && currentHour < 12) {

Do stuff...

}
```

It didn't work as long as the `currentHour < 12` is there (in the end). Yet, when I removed it, it worked without problem.

I also tried (while I didn't know it wouldn't really matter):

```
if ( currentDay !== 6 || currentDay !== 5 && currentHour < 12 ) {

Do stuff...

}
```

Again, if I remove currentHour < 12, the script works.

Is it even possible to condition when combining current day and current hour in the current release of JavaScript?

---

### Note

I need `&& currentHour < 12` just for Fridays.

Comment: Put the `OR`s inside parenteses then add the `AND`: `(... || ... || ... || ...) && ...`. `&&` is higher in precedence than `||`.

Comment: it worked for me

Comment: So the last AND will effect only the last OR? Why is it that way?

Comment: OT: `currentDay === 0 || currentDay === 1 || currentDay === 2 || currentDay === 3 || currentDay === 4 || currentDay === 5` => `currentDay >= 0 && currentDay <= 5` or `[0,1,2,3,4,5].indexOf(currentDay)>-1`

Comment: @sangoko `&&` is higher in operator precedence (it gets evaluated first). Same as in `5 + 3 * 2` yield `11` not `16`because `*` is higher than `+`.

Comment: Wouldn't this be the more readable equivalent `if( (currentDay != 6 && currentDay != 5) && currentHour < 12 ) {
    //do something
}`

Comment: list of operator precedence in js: http://www.scriptingmaster.com/javascript/operator-precedence.asp

Comment: @sangako cause you write ABC v DEF in bool algebra. Which is equal to A&B&C | D&E&F. If the operator predescendence wouldve been swapped, one would need to do (A&B&C) | (D&E&F) which will confuse many...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, if you want to compare `currentHour<12` and `currentDay==5` with the indicator `&&` you may use this code:

```
if ( currentDay === 0 || currentDay === 1 || currentDay === 2 || currentDay === 3 || currentDay === 4 || currentDay === 5 && currentHour < 12) {

Do stuff...

}
```

But if you want to compare `currentHour < 12` with all `currentDay`s you may use this code:

```
if ( (currentDay === 0 || currentDay === 1 || currentDay === 2 || currentDay === 3 || currentDay === 4 || currentDay === 5) && currentHour < 12) {

Do stuff...

}
```

However, as @RobG says, it is most pretty to do like that:

```
if ( currentDay<=5 && currentHour < 12) {

Do stuff...

}
```

---

**Edit**

Of course, if you want to only compare a `currentDay` with the `currentHour` you may do like this:

```
if ( currentDay <= 6 || (currentDay === 5 && currentHour < 12)) {

Do stuff...

}
```

Here, the operator () group the `currentDay` and the `currentHour` and compare just them without the other statement.

---

In this example, the operator `()` group all the `currentDay`s, compare they (like an if condition witch return a boolean), and next compare the boolean with `currentHour < 12` (or the next statement).

*As I understand of your question, you have a problem in order to compare all statements in your conditions. If you have some questions tell me a comment.*

*You can consult [this](http://www.scriptingmaster.com/javascript/operator-precedence.asp) page for more information about operators.*

Comment: Thank you dearly. I think I misphrased my question in the sense that I need `&& currentHour < 12` only in Friday. I've now added a note in the end of the question to make that clear.

Comment: It would be a lot less code as `currentDay < 5 || (currentDay == 5 && currentHour < 12)`.

Comment: First, thank you. Second I think you misunderstood me: I want to use the script only in Saturday (all of it), and Friday (only after 12:00 in the noon). Can you please delete code examples that doesn't deal with that? The last code example with negative comparing (!==) seems not to work.

Comment: As I understand, @sangoko, you want to execute the if statement on Saturday an Friday (after 12:00)? I edited my post in this way.

Comment: In Friday --- Before 12:00.

Comment: BTW, the first example does work, so you did understood me correctly regarding to it. But negatively it doesn't work. (with two `!==` instead of 6 `===`).

Comment: You can try this code for your last example:  `if ( currentDay === 6 || (currentDay === 5 && currentHour < 12) ) {

Do stuff...

}` In your post your last code works for all date that are not equals (`!==`) to friday and saturday (before 12:00). I correct the mistake.